# Is there a better way to create an index of an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, iteration

I made up a method to add a variable `rank`to an array of structs.
The array `friutsArray`is created like in the function `makeFriuts()`. After that, the data gets sorted and according to this, every item gets a `rank`, respectively index.

In the end I need the `FriutsWithRank`struct like it is.
But I´m wondering if there is a better, more effective way to to that. Maybe by even skipping the whole `Friuts` struct:

```
struct Friuts {
    var name: String
    var price: Double
}

struct FriutsWithRank {
    var name: String
    var price: Double
    var rank: Int
}

var friutsArray = [Friuts]()

func makeFriuts() {
    friutsArray.append(Friuts(name: "mango", price: 1.2))
    friutsArray.append(Friuts(name: "banana", price: 0.79))
    friutsArray.append(Friuts(name: "orange", price: 2.2))
}

func makeFriutsWithRank(data: [Friuts]) -> [FriutsWithRank] {

    let dataSorted = data.sorted { $1.price < $0.price }

    var datatoappend = [FriutsWithRank]()

    var i = 0
    dataSorted.forEach { fruit in
        i += 1
        let name = fruit.name
        let price = fruit.price
        let rank = i

        let result = FriutsWithRank(name: name, price: price, rank: rank)

        datatoappend.append(result)
    }
    return datatoappend
}

let friutsArrayWithRank = makeFriutsWithRank(data: friutsArray)
```

With more effective i mean not necessarily less code. I think the two arrays are now created with two iterations. Is it possible to skip the whole `Fruits` struct and work just with one struct and one iteration?.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that in the end, I need the `FriutsWithRank`struct like it is. Could skip the `Friuts` struct if possible. But definitely more readable with you suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have applied some modification on your code, please read the inline comments. Not much more optimised, but more readable for sure.

```
// Typo fixed + it is a single Fruit, not Fruits
struct Fruit {
    var name: String
    var price: Double
}


struct FruitsWithRank {
    // You already have a variable holding name and price, Friut
    // Lets just reuse Fruit object
    var fruit: Fruits
    var rank: Int
}

var fruits = [Fruit]()

func makeFruits() {
    fruits.append(Fruit(name: "mango", price: 1.2))
    fruits.append(Fruit(name: "banana", price: 0.79))
    fruits.append(Fruit(name: "orange", price: 2.2))
}

func makeFruitsWithRank(data: [Fruits]) -> [FruitsWithRank] {

    let dataSorted = data.sorted { $1.price < $0.price }
    var datatoappend = [FruitsWithRank]()
    // Use `enumerated` to get index and the object straight away
    for (index, fruit) in dataSorted.enumerated() {
        // Just init your `FruitsWithRank` with the fruit and the index
        let rankedFruit = FruitsWithRank(fruit: fruit, rank: index)
        // Add to your array
        datatoappend.append(rankedFruit)
    } 

    return datatoappend
}

let fruitsWithRank = makeFruitsWithRank(data: fruitsArray)
```

**EDIT:**
Following the edits of your question, i have applied some changes. If you need `FruitsWithRank` having name and price, you can just create [tuples](https://whatilearnedtoday.io/swift-tuples/) with name and price, and create an array straight away without any loops or appends. You can omit the `makeFruitsWithRank` function, and sort, enumerate and create your types straight on the tuple array.

```
struct FruitsWithRank {
    var rank: Int
    var name: String
    var price: Double
}

let rankedFruits: [FruitsWithRank] = [
        (name: "mango", price: 1.2), 
        (name: "banana", price: 0.79), 
        (name: "orange", price: 2.2)]
        .sorted { $0.price < $1.price }
        .enumerated()
        .map({ return FruitsWithRank(rank: $0 + 1, name: $1.name, price: $1.price) })
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end this isn't much more efficient than your code, but it is more compact:

```
func makeFriutsWithRank(data: [Friuts]) -> [FriutsWithRank] {

    let dataMapped = data.sorted { $1.price < $0.price }
        .enumerated()
        .map { FriutsWithRank(name: $1.name, price: $1.price, rank: $0 + 1) }

    return dataMapped
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it really necassary to have Struct? Because you already have sorted, the index can serve as rank.